# Is there a version control system that can handle zipped archives?

Tags: versioning

I am working with a tool that keeps the project in a zipped archive, is there a version control system that uses the diffs of the extracted files instead of the binary thing that the archive is?

Comment: out of curiousity - why do you keep your sources in zip?

Comment: my ide keeps the project in an archive (SAS Enterprise Guide)

Comment: maybe this link will help: [Using source control management with SAS Enterprise Guide](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/10/29/scm-with-sas-eg/)